# Specify latitude and longitude for Google Visualization Geochart instead of City name

Tags: google-visualization

Is it possible to specify coordinates for a city rather than the city name for a Geochart?
The second map on their documentation page (https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/geochart) uses cities.

I want to specify coordinates to make it faster to place markers on the map.
Specifying cities takes longer for large datasets because it has to find each city by name.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

You have to enter the lat/lon values as the 2 first values of the data table.

```
data.addColumn('number', 'Lat'); // Latitude Value
data.addColumn('number', 'Lon'); // Longitude Value
data.addColumn('string', 'Name'); // 
data.addColumn('number', 'Value'); // 
data.addColumn({type:'string', role:'tooltip'});

data.addRows([[33.6598257,-85.8316318," City Name",1,"Tooltip info"]]);         
data.addRows([[33.5206608,-86.80249," City Name",2,"Tooltip Info"]]);
```

I've successfully created maps with dozens of markers that load instantly with this model.
Here's an example on my website of a Map of the US with 130+ markers: http://cmoreira.net/interactive-world-maps-demo/interactive-map-load-large-number-of-markers/

Hope it helps!

Comment: AWESOME! Thank you, CMoreira.

Comment: how did you find the cities coordination ?!

Comment: anyone could help with related question, thanks http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23932714/google-jsapi-adding-invisible-data-for-marker-geocharts