# Google JSAPI: Adding Invisible Data For Marker Geocharts

Tags: google-api, google-visualization

I need to add an "invisible" column, which would be triggered on select.

Something like:

```
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('number', 'Lat'); // Latitude Value
  data.addColumn('number', 'Lon'); // Longitude Value
  data.addColumn('string', 'Name'); // 
  data.addColumn('number', 'Consumer Price Index (CPI)', 'Value'); // 
  data.addColumn('string', 'Invisible'); //
```

And later on:

```
  google.visualization.events.addListener(geomap, 'select', function() {
      var selection = geomap.getSelection()[0];
      window.location = selection[4];
  });
```

I'm getting Error message while loading the map:

```
Incompatible data table: Error: Table contains more columns than expected (Expecting 4 columns)
```

So it looks like DataTable doesn't accept my Invisible column.

Any idea how to fix that?

Comment: probably this answers my question, but if anyone knows the way without data transformation might be useful: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-visualization-api/KC6rezXugrs

Comment: The DataViews are fast - they effectively create pointer references to the underlying DataTable rather than replicate any of its contents.  The only time they can slow you down is when you do complex calculations for a calculated column, which is not necessary in your case.

Answer (score 0):

Although I haven't found the answer to my question, I've found a workaround which doesn't use DataView (data transform could potentially be slow) and therefore, it is probably much faster.

I've created another array with additional data (variable `hrefs`) in the same order as main DataTable and I do use it in the event as:

```
google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'select', function() {
    var selection = chart.getSelection();
    var row = selection[0].row;
    window.location = hrefs[row];
});
```

It works at least in Chrome ;-)

Comment: For your situation (just hiding a particular column), DataViews are going to be very fast, and will not involve extra computation.

If you see slowness resulting from using DataViews, post to the Google Group, and we'll take a look.